# div height according to window size with overflow-y: auto

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am trying to make a modal to adjust the size according to the screen size with content to be `overflow-y: auto`. I can't get it to work when my content is taking more space than a modal content container. Modal stretches fine to a max size that I set but it is not shrinking down properly.

JS:

```
const Modal = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <div className="modal-body">
        <div className="modal-body-title"></div>
        <div className="modal-body-content">
          {/* THIS IS WHERE MY CONTENT IS */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
    
export default Modal;
```

SCSS:

```
.modal {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 auto; // MY APP CONTAINER IS SET TO FLEX
  z-index: var(--z-modal);
  background: blue;

  &-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 64rem;
    max-height: 48rem;
    background: var(--c-submenus);
    box-shadow: var(--s-primary);
    padding: 1.25rem;
    margin: 4rem;

    &-title {
      background: red;
      min-height: 2.25rem;
      margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    }

    &-content {
      background: green;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

and this is what I have at the moment:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vh to fix height according to screen size.

```
vh  Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*
```

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: But that way my modal is always `max-height` when app height is bigger than content. What I trying to achieve is that modal is always smallest possible size until hit max-height

Comment: you can add max-height in "vh" if you want your modal to be wrap content if the content size is smaller than the screen.